# Strange Behavior with SwiftUI TextEditor after Copy-Pasting Content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm facing an issue with a `TextEditor` component in my SwiftUI view. Whenever I copy-paste content into the TextEditor, it begins to flicker while typing, and portions of the text content become hidden. It appears that there might be a problem with correctly determining the content size. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue or found a workaround for it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var notes = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $notes)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                .frame(height: 142)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                )
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Copy some long text into TextEditor
- Start typing into TextEditor
- Hit return key to add new line
- You will observe flickering and mentioned issue from the description.

*Edit:*

*Actually, @Banghua found we don't need to copy a long text. Just tapping several return keys until reaching the last line and then tapping letters, this behavior happens.*

[image]

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, your code works well for me in my tests, no flickering while typing. On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: I tested it on the iOS 16.1.1 and iOS 17 simulator, issue is reproducible.

Comment: Oh, first copy paste some content into it and then start typing. @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: I could not reproduce it on iOS 17.2

Comment: Well, let me check on iOS 17.2

Comment: I can reproduce it by tapping the return key at the last line. Actually, I found we don't need to copy a long text. Just tapping several return keys until reaching the last line and then tapping letters, this behavior happens.

Comment: Thanks @BanghuaZhao for confirming it.

Comment: Looks like a bug within SwiftUI `TextEditor`